# List becomes empty when ordered

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method:

```
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get { return _vehicles; }
    }
```

Which will return data. If I do the following;

```
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get { return _vehicles.OrderBy(v => v.Year).ToList(); }
    }
```

It becomes empty. If I call the orderby outside this method `myList = vehicleList.Vehicles.OrderBy(x => x.Year)` the list will contain all needed data.

I am confused as to why.

Comment: No `vehicles.OrderBy(v => v.Year).ToList();` can not return null

Comment: @I4V is completely correct. When you call `ToList()` on `IEnumerable<T>` it will either return new list (possible empty) or throw an exception if sequence is `null`

Comment: _vehicles returns a count of  0 in this case. Ill specify in the question

Comment: @PepperedLemons what is `_vehicles`? Is it simple `List<Vehicle>`? If so, then when you are adding items to this list?

Comment: `_vehicles` is a class made up of a constructor and a bunch of accessors and mutators, one of them being year. They are set according to values in a data base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a fact, that `ToList()` creates new `List<T>` instead of returning the underlying one.

So when you call:

```
var list = vehicleList.Vehicles;
list.Add(new Vehicle());
list.Add(new Vehicle());
Console.WriteLine(vehicleList.Vehicles.Count);
```

It will print `2` for your first `Vehicles` property declaration and `0` for the second one.

That's because with your second property declaration you're adding items to a `List` that was just created using `ToList()` call, not to that one from `_vehicles` backing field.

To make it work, try following:

```
public List<Vehicle> Vehicles
{
    get { return (_vehicles = _vehicles.OrderBy(v => v.Year).ToList()); }
}
```

Or use `List<T>.Sort` method instead of `OrderBy` LINQ extension method:

```
public List<Vehicle> Vehicles
{
    get
    {
        _vehicles.Sort((v1, v2) => v1.Year.CompareTo(v2.Year));
        return _vehicles;
    }
}
```

But to make things clear: **You should highly consider, that overall idea of having that kind of property is wrong.** You need your data to always be sorted? Use proper data structure, like `SortedList<int, Vehicle>` instead of standard `List` that is sorted every time property getter is being fired.

Comment: @Servy You're totally right! But that's not the case here. OP just wonder why his property does not work. The overall idea of having a property like that is not under discussion here. If it did, I would suggest using `SortedList<int, Vehicle>` instead of `List<Vehicle>`.

Comment: @Servy You're right again. I should have mentioned that. Updated my answer to make it clear. Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, you're returning a reference to the list, not a copy of the list.  If the internal list is modified at a later point then the outer list will be able to observe those changes (because it's the same list after all).

When you use LINQ's `OrderBy` method from outside of the list it is going to defer execution.  It won't be until you actually iterate the results of that sequence that it will go and look into the list; at which point is has most likely already been changed.

When you use `ToList` in the property getter you are taking a copy of the list, rather than just copying the *reference* to it, so it's basically a snapshot of that moment in time.  At the time you get the property the list is [apparently] empty, but when it you iterate it it's [apparently] not.

If it's important to both have this ability to defer execution, and also that the items in this property always be accessed based on a sort not manually applied by the caller, then you can use something like this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Vehicles
{
    get { return _vehicles.OrderBy(v => v.Year); }
}
```

That said, if it's important that the collection always be sorted when accessed it may be preferable to simply store the items in a sorted manor, so that accessing the items is cheap.  Consider instead using something like a `SortedSet` instead of a `List`.